# Bpel Oracle Soa Suite. Are there any way to filter business events by properties defined in a configPlan?

Tags: oracle11g, bpel, soa-suite

I'm trying to filter an event by a property but it doesn't work. However, if I filter it by a value, it works fine. There are any way to filter my events by a value defined in the configPlan file?.

I'm trying to do this:

That doesn't work:

```
<business-events>
  <subscribe xmlns:sub1="http://www.vxxxxxx/events/edl/xxx"
             name="sub1:UxxxxxxxxEvent" consistency="oneAndOnlyOne"
             runAsRoles="$publisher">
    <filter>
      <xpath xmlns:co="http://www.vxxxxxx/schema/xxx/Common"
             xmlns:tns="http://www.vxxxxxx/schema/xxx/Uxxx"
             xmlns:be="http://oracle.com/fabric/businessEvent"
             expression='/be:business-event/be:content/tns:Uxxxxxxx_v1.0/@enviroment = ora:getPreference('enviroment')'/>
    </filter>
  </subscribe>
```

It works:

```
<business-events>
  <subscribe xmlns:sub1="http://www.vxxxxxx/events/edl/xxx"
             name="sub1:UxxxxxxxxEvent" consistency="oneAndOnlyOne"
             runAsRoles="$publisher">
    <filter>
      <xpath xmlns:co="http://www.vxxxxxx/schema/xxx/Common"
             xmlns:tns="http://www.vxxxxxx/schema/xxx/Uxxx"
             xmlns:be="http://oracle.com/fabric/businessEvent"
             expression="/be:business-event/be:content/tns:Uxxxxxxx_v1.0/@enviroment = 'TEST'"/>
    </filter>
  </subscribe>
```

Tanks.

Comment: You have probably found this out by now, but is it possible that your environment property is stored in "environment" instead of "enviroment"?